# Extracting the substring of the first array to get the matching value from the second array in PHP

Tags: php

Given as an example:

```
$store = {A, B, C, D, E}

$price = {2, 10, 1, 500, 20}
```

Store[0]'s value is 2, [1] is 10, and so on. I'd like to know how to do that. I tried using min() but to no avail (unless I missed something out). Here's what I've done so far:

```
$x;

for ($x = $price.Count - 1; $x >= 0; $x--)

{

//this is the part where I can't figure it out
//compare prices here
//get the lowest price
//x = theSubstringOfTheLowestPrice

}

echo $store[x];
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that `A = 2`, `B = 10`, `C = 1`, etc?

Comment: First - it is uncleat what you triying to do. Find min price? Use `min`. And then what? You want to get the according store? And second - your code is not in php.

Comment: here is no array...it is object

Comment: @fubar yes, pretty much like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Your PHP code is not valid: `$price = {A}` means you must have constant A and php arrays are enclosed with `array()` or `[]`.
2. Use `array_combine()` to create key-value pairs ([demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f37f498c845e9f9e3d3385cbc8fed3f632a443a7)):

```
$store = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

$price = [2, 10, 1, 500, 20];

$range = array_combine($store, $price);

var_dump($range['D']); // 500
```

Comment: @Kyle Yes, but you can do it directly on `$price` array.

Comment: assuming I did min($range), can i call $store that matches the result of min($range)? Say the answer for min is 1, how can I call store 'C'?

Comment: @Kyle Two options: 1: switch arguments of `array_combine`, then you can do `$range[min($price)]`; 2. use `array_search(min($price), $range)` to get KEY of 1 that is `C`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing these key, value pairs in 2 separate arrays, let's associate them with one like so:

```
>>>$storePrices = [
    "A" => 2,
    "B" => 10,
    "C" => 1,
    "D" => 500,
    "E" => 20
]
```

Now to get the lowest store price in your `$storePrices` array, use can use `min()`.

```
>>>min($storePrices)
=> 1
```

If you wish to get the associated store from the given minimum price, you can achieve it like this:

```
>>>array_search(1, $storePrices)
=> "C"
```

Or

```
>>>array_search(min($storePrices), $storePrices)
=> "C"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use associative arrays like this:

```
$prices = [ 'A' => 20, 'B' => 30, 'C' => 10];
```

And then calculate the minimum price like so:

```
$result = array_keys($prices, min($prices));
```

Here is the var_dump for `$result`:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  string(1) "C"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$store = array(A, B, C, D, E);
$price = array(2, 10, 1, 500, 20);

$index=array_search(min($price), $price); 
echo $store[$index];
```

Comment: now its true the i use the wrong bracket...now it works fine